# How to send a message to node.js server?

Tags: node.js

How would I send a command to Node.js

I have a jquery / javascript page which detects on keypress W,A,S Or D and then triggers an event to change the canvas.

The next step in this is to then trigger a event on a Node.js server using (I think) Websockets.

Most tutorials I have found are the other way around with sending data to the client.

Does anyone have places with tutorials on how I would do this?

Thanks - Ryan

Comment: Whatever you send is data. How you server interprets it is an other story. For example, on W key pressed, send `W` to socket. String containg W symbol is data being sent. When server gets that W, he knows that it means `Command Move Forward` and moves (or whatever command you want). So, `switch(symblol)` is your friend here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use web sockets, tutorial is here http://socket.io/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with normal ajax calls to Node.js. If you want something more fancy checkout socket.io.